# Node.js REPL with vim keybindings AND method/variable completion

Tags: node.js, syntax, read-eval-print-loop, code-completion, tab-completion

As far as I know, the standard way to get vim keybindings in the Node REPL is to use `rlwrap` like so:

`NODE_NO_READLINE=1 rlwrap node`

This, however, kills method and variable tab-completion. Is there some workaround?

Comment: Can I ask what's the use case here?

Comment: Uhm. Being more productive in the REPL by using familiar vim keybindings?

Comment: It's quite common to use vim bindings outside vim, isn't it? For example, I use them in ZSH, in bash, and in ipython (all of which are REPLs). Maybe I didn't understand your question?

Comment: To be honest I don't use Vim bindings outside Vim, but I don't spend that much time in bash, zsh or some kind of REPL.

Comment: For me it's like: 25% REPL 65% browser and 10% trying to make friends with the rest of the GUI world ;-)

Comment: It's hard to find a good `solution` to the question. To avoid editing in the node *REPL*, I have to use a lot **.load myfile.js**. This might be better than **Perl -d**, if we can call it's `perl's` **REPL**.

Answer (score 1):

Seems impossible. You can put your own completion file in /usr/share/rlwrap/completions and have some primitive(no variables) completion but that seems useless in a repl.

Here's the explanation from the rlwrap author himself:

[Can rlwrap use a wrapped command's own TAB completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210931/is-there-a-way-of-running-rlwrap-with-tab-completion-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

It's two years out of date, (as is this question), but hey.

> https://github.com/thlorenz/readline-vim

Comment: This seems like a library, not a REPL. They have created their own REPL example in the examples section, but this doesn't allow running the default REPL. Am I missing something?

Comment: Interesting, you're right. If anybody's still having this problem, it's probably the work of ~15 minutes to publish a monkey-patched REPL to npm with a `bin` field — make it happen! `<3`