# Is it possible to make the interactive Node.js shell use vi mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a minor inconvenience, but since nobody seems to have asked it, here it is:

With Python, I can place `set editing-mode vi` in `~/.inputrc` and then the Python and iPython interactive shells will use vi mode. Is it possible to do something similar with Node.js?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rlwrap`, but it comes at a price - you will loose native node `TAB` completion (you can find details here: [Can rlwrap use a wrapped command's own TAB completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210931/is-there-a-way-of-running-rlwrap-with-tab-completion-disabled)):

```
rlwrap -a -- node
```