# Readline type wrapper that scrolls entire multiline commands at one time

Tags: terminal, readline, read-eval-print-loop

I am using an enhanced `kotlin` REPL and have entered a multi-line code snippet:

```
$rlwrap bin/ki.sh
ki-shell 0.3/1.4.21
type :h for help
[0] fun reformat(
    str: String,
    normalizeCase: Boolean = true,
    upperCaseFirstLetter: Boolean = true,
    divideByCamelHumps: Boolean = false,
    wordSeparator: Char = ' ',
)
 {
  println("In reformat")
}
```

If you were observant you may have noticed that the kotlin shell had been "wrapped" with `rlwrap`.  I had hoped that would provide a single keystroke to scroll past that multi-line command. However as can be seen in the following screenshot the up-arrow key (and likewise shift- or option- or command- or control- up-arrow) only moves up a single line at a time

[image]

So is there any such wrapper for REPL-like utilities that will enable multi-line scrolling?

Note that the `scala` REPL does have the multi-line scrolling as does `ipython` under certain circumstances (in my case only under `iTerm` but not under `Terminal`).

I am on `macOS Catalina` but expect the answer would apply equally to most *NIX variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `rlwrap` manual:

```
-m, --multi-line [newline_substitute]
  Enable  multi-line input using a "newline substitute" character
  sequence (" \ ", [space-backslash-space] by default). Newline sub‐
  stitutes are translated to newlines before sending the input to 
  command.  With this option, you can call an external  editor  
  $RLWRAP_EDITOR  on  the  (expanded)  current  input  with the    
  rlwrap_call_editor key (CTRL-^ by default)
```

When using  `rlwrap -m`, pressing <kbd>CTRL+^</kbd> will drop you  into an editor where you can edit your multi-line snippet. Upon exiting the editor, the snippet will be sent to the `rlwrap`ped command, and also be put into the `rlwrap` history as *one* single line (with newlines replaced by the "newline substitute")  Moving through history with <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> will still show those snippets as *one* single line, but you can expand them at any moment into multi-line text within your editor by pressing <kbd>CTRL+^</kbd> again

Not *exactly* what you're looking for, but it *does* scroll entire multiline commands at a time, which I like better than e.g. `ipython` where you still (at least with the terminals I use) have to press <kbd>↑</kbd> a couple times to move past a large function definition.

Of course, as with any readline wrapper, there are donwsides: you will [lose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210931/can-rlwrap-use-a-wrapped-commands-own-tab-completion)  any context-sensitive completion your CLI might have had, and even the paltry `rlwrap` completion mechanism will not work within the multi-line-editor.

**Setup:**

It should work "out of the box" by just issuing

```sh
$ rlwrap -m -a <my_cli_command> # -a because your cli probably 
                                # does some line editing already
```

Some tweaks:

- If you prefer a diffferent editor, add a line
  `export RLWRAP_EDITOR='<my_editor_of_choice>[-opts]` in your `.bashrc`. The default is `vi +%L`. `%F`, `%L` and `%C` in `RLWRAP_EDITOR` will be replaced by filename, line and column, respectively, in order to drop you into the editor at the very spot where the cursor was in `rlwrap`
- To use a different editing hotkey, add a line like `"\C-b":rlwrap-call-editor` to `~/.inputrc` (<kbd>CTRL+^</kbd> is the default)
- To use a different "newline substitute" (e.g. "||") , add an argument to `-m` like in `rlwrap -m'||'` (the default is `' \ '`)
- if your `editor_of_choice` does syntax colouring based on filename extensions, add an argument `-M.ext` (default: no extension)

For example:

```sh
export RLWRAP_EDITOR='my_edit --auto-save-on-exit %F:%L'
# ... or put the above in .bashrc
rlwrap -a -m': ' -M_bas QLSuperBasic # ... those were the days
```

Comment: This looks v promising. I guess it would be necessary to find a `.kt` syntax file?  I'm looking into that

Comment: That depends on your editor. I'm an `emacs` guy, and for that there certainly exists a kotlin-"mode" . If you specify that the `.kt` file extension needs kotlin-mode Bob's your uncle..

Comment: Would you be able to piece together what the command line would be here?  This seems to be heading towards/contain the correct answer but getting to a functioning result is quite challenging .  I'm  considering to ask a separate question about using `rlwrap` with kotlin

Comment: I didn't have much luck with installing the kotlin shell, so I'll try to give a general roadmap. Be aware that with any readline wrapper you'll also _lose_ some functionality, like context-aware completion.